# Generate series of integer based on the condition of another column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window

I have the following datatable

```
create table test.my_table
(
  date                    date,
  daily_cumulative_precip real
);


INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-11', 0.508);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-12', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-13', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-14', 2.032);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-15', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-16', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-17', 21.842);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-18', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-19', 0);
INSERT INTO test.my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip) VALUES ('2016-07-20', 0);
```

I would like to create and assign values in a new column named 'delta' based on `daily_cumulative_precip`. I would like to have `delta = 0` when `daily_cumulative_precip > 0`, `delta = 1` when `daily_cumulative_precip = 0` on that day and the previous day, `delta = 2` when  `daily_cumulative_precip = 0` on that day and the previous 1 days, and `delta = 3` when `daily_cumulative_precip = 0` on that day and the previous 2 days. For this specific datatable, `delta` should be

```
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3
```

I have the following but it does not produce the desired result

```
SELECT *,
      CASE
        WHEN daily_cumulative_precip > 0 THEN 0
        --ELSE date - first_value(date) OVER (ORDER BY date)
          ELSE date - lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY date)
          END AS delta
FROM "test".my_table
ORDER BY date;
```

I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your particular data, the following works:

```
select t.*,
       (date - max(date) filter (where daily_cumulative_precip > 0) over (order by date))
from my_table t
order by date;
```

This gets the most recent date where the value is greater than 0.

This assumes that the first day has a value greater than 0.  If this is not always the case, then:

```
select t.*,
       (date -
        coalesce(max(date) filter (where daily_cumulative_precip > 0) over (order by date),
                 min(date) over (order by date)
                )
       ) as seqnum
from my_table t
order by date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=07d673d91a18acc5fb603b05b2f2e464) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution.  The idea is to first generate a value that will partition your records into distinct groups, then you can calculate the delta for each group.

```
with partitions as (
select date
     , daily_cumulative_precip
     , sum(case when daily_cumulative_precip <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       over (order by date) grp
  from my_table
)
select date
     , daily_cumulative_precip
     , row_number() over (partition by grp order by date) - 1 delta
  from partitions;
```